# Booking system remove all saved bookings during a period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple bookings in pending status. But 1 of them is paid and the status is now confirmed.

Here is an example of what I have :

```
id |       start_date       |        end_date       |  status
   |                        |                       |
1  |   2019-06-10 08:00:00  |  2019-06-10 20:00:00  |  pending    <-- To delete
2  |   2019-06-10 10:00:00  |  2019-06-10 13:00:00  |  confirmed
3  |   2019-06-09 06:00:00  |  2019-06-11 11:00:00  |  pending    <-- To delete
4  |   2019-06-10 21:00:00  |  2019-06-10 22:00:00  |  pending    <-- Keep it
5  |   2019-06-10 11:00:00  |  2019-06-10 12:00:00  |  pending    <-- To delete
```

The id 2 is confirmed and I need to delete all other bookings in pending status who are in the same period of the confirmed status.

So I need to delete ids 1, 3 and 5

How can I do that with SQL query ?

I thought about but I'm not sure it will cover all possible cases:

```
DELETE FROM booking 
WHERE status = 'pending' 
AND start_date <= '2019-06-10 10:00:00' 
AND end_date >= '2019-06-10 13:00:00'
```

Comment: Your query is almost right, you'll be deleting id 2 with this. You should have `status='pending'` or else if you have other statuses you might want `status!='confirmed'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want overlapping intervals.  This would be:

```
DELETE b
    FROM booking b
    WHERE b.status = 'pending' AND
          b.end_date >= '2019-06-10 10:00:00' AND
          b.start_date <= '2019-06-10 13:00:00';
```

Two intervals overlap if the second ends on or after the first starts, and the second starts on or before the first ends.

Comment: I think OP actually wants `b.status = 'pending'`

Comment: Yes my bad for 'confirmed'. Thank you I give a try

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,start_date DATETIME NOT NULL
,end_date DATETIME NOT NULL
,status VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2019-06-10 08:00:00','2019-06-10 20:00:00','pending'),
(2,'2019-06-10 10:00:00','2019-06-10 13:00:00','confirmed'),
(3,'2019-06-09 06:00:00','2019-06-11 11:00:00','pending'),
(4,'2019-06-10 21:00:00','2019-06-10 22:00:00','pending'),
(5,'2019-06-10 11:00:00','2019-06-10 12:00:00','pending');

DELETE y 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.start_date <= x.end_date 
   AND y.end_date > x.start_date 
 WHERE x.status = 'confirmed' 
   AND y.id <> x.id;

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | start_date          | end_date            | status    |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|  2 | 2019-06-10 10:00:00 | 2019-06-10 13:00:00 | confirmed |
|  4 | 2019-06-10 21:00:00 | 2019-06-10 22:00:00 | pending   |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Join the same table ? :o it's just for the example right ? to get the value ?

Comment: Yeah that's why I asked why. My reply is not pejorative.

Comment: I know. That's why I added a smiley face.